# How to get pseudo element to respect immediate parent's width and ignore sibling's width

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a few columns of items that when hovered will display an animated underline effect. The issue I am having is that the item in each column with the most text is setting the width for all of it's siblings. For example, two items in the same column will have the same pseudo element width, even if one of the item's content is much shorter than the other.

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
 .container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 3vw;
}
 .item {
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 19px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
   font-size: 12px;
}
 .item::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  bottom: 0;
  transition: 0.4s transform ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: solid 2px tomato;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}
 .item:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="item">Long Phrase Goes Here</a>
  <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
  <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
  <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
  <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="item">Long Phrase Goes Here</a>
  <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
  <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
  <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
  <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have `display: block;flex-direction: column;` on the `.container` Is this intentional ? because it doesn't serve any purpose `display:block` is the default for `div` elements, and `flex-direction` only works if the display is set to `flex`

Comment: @zohirsalak whoops no that was my mistake. flex / column. accidentally had block in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add `align-items: flex-start` on `.container` so the items will take the width of their content:

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 3vw;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.item {
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 19px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.item::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  bottom: 0;
  transition: 0.4s transform ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: solid 2px tomato;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}

.item:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="item">Long Phrase Goes Here</a>
    <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
    <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
    <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
    <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="item">Long Phrase Goes Here</a>
    <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
    <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
    <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
    <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

One Possible solution is to add `margin-right:auto` to all `.item`

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 3vw;
}

.item {
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 19px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 12px;
  
  display: block; /* Not really needed */
  margin-right: auto; /* Added */
  
  /* to visualize  */
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  bottom: 0;
  transition: 0.4s transform ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: solid 2px tomato;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}

.item:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="item">Long Phrase Goes Here</a>
    <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
    <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
    <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
    <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="item">Long Phrase Goes Here</a>
    <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
    <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
    <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
    <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`display:block` on `.item` is causing this... for the effect that you want, have each item inside a `ul li` as in the **first column/container** of the code below:

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-top: 20vh;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 3vw;
}

.container:nth-child(2) .item,
.container:nth-child(3) .item {
  display: block;
}

.item {
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 19px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: relative;
}

.item::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  bottom: 0;
  transition: 0.4s transform ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: solid 2px tomato;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}

.item:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

.container ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="#" class="item">Long Phrase Goes Here</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a> </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="item">Long Phrase Goes Here</a>
    <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
    <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
    <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
    <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="item">Long Phrase Goes Here</a>
    <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
    <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
    <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
    <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
    <a href="#" class="item">Test Test</a>
  </div>
</div>
```